# can't remove top white line in accordionPanel tabs primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces, tabs

I have tried to remove the accordion tab top line with css but it doesn't go.
The following is my code snipset .I have tried several css styles but it does not respond.Kindly advice on how to remove the default bar above each tab in the accordion.

```
        <div class="ui-g" style="margin-left: 40px ;background:#A9A9A9;width: 80% ">
                        <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="null" style="width: 80% ;">
                            <p:tab title="Analysis" titleStyle="background:#A9A9A9;color:black;width:100px;border-style:none;outline:none;">
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Overview" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page1')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Export" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page3')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}"  onclick="PFE('ppanel').toggle()"  update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Overview" titleStyle="background:#A9A9A9;color:black;width:100px;border-style:none;outline:none;">
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Overview" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page1')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Export" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page3')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Analysis" titleStyle="background:#A9A9A9;color:black;width:100px;border-style:none;outline:none;">
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Overview" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page1')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Export" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page3')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Charts" titleStyle="background:#A9A9A9;color:black;width:100px;border-style:none;outline:none;">
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Overview" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page1')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Export" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page3')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Export" titleStyle="background:#A9A9A9;color:black;width:100px;border-style:none;outline:none;">
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Overview" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page1')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton  style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/>
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Export" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page3')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                                <p:commandButton   style="background:#A9A9A9;color: black;width:100px;border-style: none;padding: 0px;outline:none;" value="Analysis" actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" update=":mainForm:content"/> 
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:accordionPanel>
                    </div>

     <h:outputStylesheet id="layoutCSS">  
        .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{
        background:#A9A9A9;
        }
        .ui-button{
        display:none !important;
        }
    </h:outputStylesheet>
```

Comment: Edit your question and post what css have you tried?

Comment: Please check on the above snipset.The issue is the white back above each tab in the accordion when I give the accordionpanel a background color

Answer (score 0):

Try with this selector

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    border-top: none;
}
```

or if you need to hide it only for active tabs, yo can use this one

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active {
    border-top: none;
}
```